# Can't connect to Amazon AWS EC2 Instance (SFTP or SSH) on a new network

Tags: ssh, sftp, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

On most networks I can connect fine. However on this new wifi network I can't connect. FileZilla just says that the connection timed out.

Comment: what is that new network? your one, or a public one? Do you have issue only with Amazon?

Comment: It's just a new wifi network at a house I just moved into. Yeah, the issue is only with AWS? I can SSH into other networks, but I don't have any other SFTP connections I can test.

Comment: do you perhaps use securitygroups that filter access to your AWS instance? It might contain your old IP and needs to be updated with the new one.